# PHP Wamp doesn't run

Tags: php, wamp

I am trying to run WAMP under my XP. I installed it to C:/wamp, than copied old php files for example like test.php to the www folder in wamp folder, than run it throungh browser from adress file:///C:/wamp/www/test.php. It includes 
< ?echo("a");? >

but it still run like html without running code and showing php in source code.

What am I doing wrong?

I was thinking if there exist some browser which will automatically executes php and includes mysql database apache.

Is there something?

And at best run ajax and asp serverside parts

Comment: Can you run a page like test.php with the code: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`?

Comment: No, I can't. It will return nothing only html code with it uninterpreted in source code. That's why i'm searching that browser.

Answer (score 4):

You are showing the file directly by the browser, nothing related to wamp.

What you should do is start wamp (maybe need some config, for example the path, the port .)

Then access your page like : `http://localhost/test.php`.

Comment: +1 Yes, as xdazz said, you are trying to hit your file directly. Just having a webserver running on your machine when you open a php file doesn't mean the webserver is going to do anything. You actually need to send an HTTP request **through** your webserver **for** the test.php file. Then, if your webserver is set up to run the PHP interpreter, it will parse your file and return the appropriate HTML.

Comment: If `c:/wamp/www/` is your server's DocumentRoot, then xdazz's suggestion of `http://localhost/test.php` should work. A more advanced setup would be to set up local domains in your host file and create virtual hosts for each locally hosted site.

Comment: Please can you tell me where could I find some config manual to do it, because to this moment I was only using the pre-configurated free-hosting server