# How to get set up for learning PHP?

Tags: php, html, apache, wamp, installation

I have downloaded WAMP to try to learn PHP on, and am having trouble getting it to work as expected whenever trying to follow along in PHP tutorials.

Either what I get back in my browser is raw PHP (as shown below in "PHP Test 1"), or nothing at all (as shown below in "PHP Test 2").  I'm just trying to learn the basics of PHP, and am finding this to be very frustrating. Can anyone help? What do I need to do get PHP working, or what should I try?

Originally I was going to post screen shots to better describe the problem I'm having, as well as to better help others who are experiencing the same problem, but was not allowed to due to something about not having enough "points". Anyway, what I was originally trying to post can be found here:

https://sites.google.com/site/bluedog4678/

Comment: study some tutorial, make some projects, visit http://php.net/docs.php , http://www.w3schools.com/php/ for complete learning

Comment: Sorry, but this is a server configuration problem, NOT a programming question.

Comment: @sourabhkasliwal: recommending [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) for learning PHP is like telling people to play in traffic so they can learn how to drive.

Comment: [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10565154/689579 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/15725860/689579

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start `WAMPP` then type this in the address bar: `localhost/PHP_TEST_1.php`.

You are currently opening a simple file without running WAMPP you need to run it through localhost.

Comment: I thought dragging and dropping the file into the browser was the same thing as typing the URL in with the "localhost" part, but apparently not. Anyway, what you suggested worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't access your files directly. Normally with simulated apache-servers you need to type in "localhost" to let it render correctly

**EDIT**
If you want to select a file it would be "localhost/"

Comment: If what you mean by "accessing files directly" entails double clicking on the PHP file. I haven't been doing that. I've been draging the files from the WWW directory in WAMP to the browser, or typing the name of the PHP file into the browser before trying to get it to render. Neither has made in difference in terms of the output I am getting. It's all either raw PHP, or no PHP at all regardless of whether I drag and drop, or type out the URL in the browser.

Comment: Apparently you are right, and I just misunderstood. Thanks.

Comment: I think I worded that somewhat unclear. Basically what I meant was that in order to look at the processed php-code with a local webserver you need to type in localhost. Otherwise you will just access it through the explorer instead of the webserver and will thus not get the wished result -> not compiled php-code